# VBA For Each Loop only excutes once and then stops

Tags: vba, excel

I made a VBA macro that has the goal of doing several find and replaces on a database using a set of items in a table. I  used a for each loop to try to iterate through each cell in the first column, but it only executes a find and replace on the items in the first column.

The table has two columns, "Replace What" and "Replace With" so i used find and replace to look for the item in the first column and used the offset function to replace it with the corresponding item in the next column.

How can I make this loop work?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
Sub FindReplace()
Dim RepList As Range, RepItem As Range



    Set RepList = Worksheets("Supply Replacement").Range("Table4[Replace What]")

    For Each RepItem In RepList.Cells

        Cells.replace What:=RepList.Value, Replacement:=RepList.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Next RepItem
```

End Sub

Comment: Isn't RepItem supposed to be a "Variant"?

Answer (score 1):

Within your loop you should be working with `RepItem`, not `RepList`:

```
Sub FindReplace()
Dim RepList As Range, RepItem As Range



    Set RepList = Worksheets("Supply Replacement").Range("Table4[Replace What]")

    For Each RepItem In RepList.Cells

        Cells.replace What:=RepItem.Value, Replacement:=RepItem.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Next RepItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow what a dopey mistake. Thanks, Tim