# gett offset() coordinates of .each() element in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you do this?

So far this is what I'm trying:

```
var blogHeaders = $('.coa-content h2');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    blogHeaders.each(function(i) {
        console.log(blogHeaders[i].offset().top);
    });
})
```

This block of code is giving me the following:

> VM941:6 Uncaught TypeError: blogHeaders[i].offset is not a function

I tried looking up "offset() for each item in loop" on here, these were the first 4 results:

[VBA For Each Loop only excutes once and then stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063556/vba-for-each-loop-only-excutes-once-and-then-stops)

[WordPress Custom Post Loop / alternating layout for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275801/wordpress-custom-post-loop-alternating-layout-for-each-item)

[Shifting scatter points for each array for delta x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463547/shifting-scatter-points-for-each-array-for-delta-x)

[Check if array has [0][1][2] or just single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521729/check-if-array-has-012-or-just-single-item)

Unfortunately, none of these answers are relevant to my question.

I googled "offset() multiple elements in loop javascript" but couldn't find any relevant answers there, either.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I taking the wrong approach here?

Comment: does `console.log($(blogHeaders[i]).offset().top);` work ?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/625941/4825796

Comment: interesting, it does, howcome I have to do that? I thought the variable represented that, no?

Comment: this `$()` pretty much wraps a DOM object into a jquery object.  `.offset()` can only be called on a jquery object.  Also like the link shows, when you take a `jquery` object and do `blogHeaders[0]` it returns a regular DOM object.

Comment: @kawnah The iteration variable in `.each()` contains the DOM element, not the element wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: This is true of most of the jQuery functions that take callback functions.

Comment: It's the reason you have to write `$(this)` in jQuery event handlers.